# Pytest not giving proper output in terminal

Tags: python, linux, pytest

I've set up a simple pytest:

```
import py.test

blah(x):
    return x+1

test_blah():
    assert blah(1)==6

test_blah()
```

Now, when I run this from bash, it does give me an AssertionError (and none if I set ==2, so it clearly kinda works), but it doesn't give me the proper kind of output as seen here in the fourth code block: http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html

I simply get the standard output format that I'd get without using pytest. E.g.:

```
Traceback (most revent call last):
    functions and lines, etc.
AssertionError
```

What am I doing wrong/misunderstanding? Help appreciated!

Comment: Please also note that the `py.test` import name is deprecated and you should use `import pytest` in new code when you can.

Comment: @flub import pytest doesn't work since I'm using python 2.7.something, not 3.something.

Comment: Err, the import name has nothing to do with python 2.7 or 3.x.  The recommended import name is `pytest` in either case.

Comment: @flub well, if i do import pytest it tells me it doesn't exist, py.test works fine :)

Comment: The only reason I can think for that is that you have a *very* old version of py/pytest installed.  I would certainly recommend to use the most recent 2.6.x version which pip would install for you.

Comment: @fub I have py.test 1.3.4. I ran the installation a few months back, using "sudo apt-get install python-py", which I was told to do by my professor. We're using 2.x version pf python, not 3.x

Comment: py.test 1.3.4 is a *very* old version of py.test and most documentation and information you will find for it will no longer match.  So I would recommend you learn about pip and use it to install py.test as described here: http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the test function yourself in the last line:

```
test_blah()
```

You have to let pytest discover and run the tests. Remove that line and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for a reply!
When I remove the line, nothing happens. No error or anything.

Comment: Nevermind, that problem was unrelated. Your answer is technically correct when it comes to answering the problem I had.